# Can not access certain websites from my MacBook or iPhone [WiFi]

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

I can't access certain websites from either my MacBook nor from my iPhone when connected to my WiFi network, but the same websites can be reached from a Windows computer connected on the same network. Three days ago everything worked, but then it stopped working.

This is what happens when I try to ping it:

```
PING ilpost.it (151.1.175.113): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
...
```

And when I try to traceroute it:

```
host-001:~ j$ traceroute www.ilpost.it
traceroute to ilpost.it (151.1.175.113), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  vodafonedslrouter (192.168.1.1)  2.965 ms  0.743 ms  0.745 ms
 2  * 2.96.54.77.rev.vodafone.pt (77.54.96.2)  12.076 ms  10.871 ms
 3  77.41.30.213.rev.vodafone.pt (213.30.41.77)  14.145 ms  10.693 ms  11.960 ms
 4  85.205.11.49 (85.205.11.49)  9.658 ms  8.946 ms  9.085 ms
 5  85.205.13.105 (85.205.13.105)  57.497 ms  57.621 ms  48.080 ms
 6  188.111.129.17 (188.111.129.17)  49.483 ms  51.338 ms  48.852 ms
 7  85.205.25.174 (85.205.25.174)  47.891 ms  49.219 ms  47.821 ms
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
```

I've flushed my DNS cache but nothing changed.

This is quite dramatic as it seems to depend on 85.205.25.174 hop and I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: From where do you try to access theses domains?

Comment: Maybe check to see that the Mac has the same DNS servers as the Windows box.

Comment: I'd check the DNS too, but what websites in particular can't you reach? Is your hosts file to blame?

Answer (score 1):

Ping (ICMP) packets can be blocked though you are still able to access the website.

Telnet to port 80 is actually a better test to verify whether you are able to connect or not.

Over here connecting to http://ilpost.it results in no problem:

```
$ telnet ilpost.it 80                                                                   (28-09-12 13:58)
Trying 151.1.175.113...
Connected to ilpost.it.
```

Although ilpost.it redirects to http://www.ilpost.it/